# Combine lists of strings element-wise with special rules

Tags: python

I am new to python and I'm trying to modify an existing program. I have several lists and I need to perform an operation on them in a sorted way. for example if I have the following lists:

```
list_A = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
list_B = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5']
```

I want to get a new list with `elements = ['A1B1', 'A2B2', 'A3B3', 'B4B5']` (i.e combine alternating elements till the smaller array runs out then combine remaining elements from the large array.

This is an example for 2 lists but I'm trying to do this for N lists.

Is there a 'pythonic' way of achieving this?

EDIT: Adding more info for the N>3 case (and made the lists bigger to show them more clearly).

```
list_A = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6']
list_B = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6']
list_C = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']
```

Start with the 'smallest' list and start pairing. For now I am handling a case where there is one shorter list and the others are the same lengths. So either A or B below would work.

Expected output: `['C1B1', 'C2B2', 'C3B3', 'C4B4', 'B5B6', 'A1A2', 'A3A4', 'A5A6']`

Comment: What does the question in your title have to do with the question in the post?

Comment: How does your excess elements policy translate to the N>2 case?

Comment: Too vauge to get an answer here, add more details so we know and as @timgeb said, your question has nothing to do with the content of your post.

Comment: What a shame, in principle this would be a good question that you could take on with Python's iteration magic. Too bad it's so underpecified.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
Among other things, you should provide your best code so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not specify what happens for the N > 3 (or above) case when one of the lists is empty but the other two have an (possibly unequal) amount of elements left.

Anyway, I had some fun implementing this recursive solution, so for what it's worth, here it is.

```
list_A = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
list_B = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5']
list_C = ['C1', 'C2']

def combine(*lists):
    lists = filter(None, lists)
    if not lists:
        return []
    if len(lists) == 1:
        return [''.join(lists[0])]

    minlen = len(min(lists, key=len))
    head = [''.join(x) for x in zip(*lists)]
    tail = [l[minlen:] for l in lists]

    return head + combine(*tail)

a = combine(list_A, list_B)
b = combine(list_A, list_B, list_C)

print a # ['A1B1', 'A2B2', 'A3B3', 'B4B5']
print b # ['A1B1C1', 'A2B2C2', 'A3B3', 'B4B5']
```

It works as follows: as long as not all lists are exhausted, the algorithm will continue to zip the elements of the remaining lists together. Once only a single list has items left, those are concatenated into a single string and appended to the result. This may or may not be what you want for the N > 2 case.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I guess more info was needed in my original question. But i think your code is really good starting point for my solution!

Answer (score -1):

```
# Notice:  the lists are composed of integers...
>>> a_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b_list = [4, 5, 6]
>>> c_list = [7, 8, 9]
>>> def cat(a_list):
...     string = ''
...     for i in a_list:
...             string += str(i)  # so we convert them to string.
...     return string
... 
>>> # Using a list comprehension and an un-named variable, along with the
>>> # zip() function.
>>> [cat(_) for _ in zip(a_list, b_list, c_list)]
['147', '258', '369']
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the content of the question? Even if the full specification of the output is unclear, a minimal requirement is to have uneven list lengths.